# Pause the timer with a button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am making a timer but am unsure of how to pause it when the button is triggered.
I have attempted to make a boolean `@State` but I am yet unsure how to pause the timer when the button is triggered. Please review my code below...

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var isTimeStarted = false
    @State var to: CGFloat = 0
    @State var timeDuration = 60
    @State var time = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State var isPaused = false
    @State private var count = 0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .trim(from: 0, to: self.to)
                        .stroke(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.white, Color.white.opacity(0.2)]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 15.6, lineCap: .round))
                        .shadow(radius: 8)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
                        .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: 180), axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 110))
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                        .animation(.easeOut)
                        .padding()
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                    Text("\(self.timeDuration, specifier: formatTime())")
                        .font(.system(size: 17.5, design: .rounded))
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                }
                Button {
                    isPaused = true
                } label: {
                    ZStack {
                        BlurView2(style: .systemThinMaterialDark)
                            .frame(width: 145, height: 45)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                            .cornerRadius(30)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        Image(systemName: "pause")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .shadow(radius: 10)
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        .onAppear {
            self.timeDuration = 60
            withAnimation(.default) {
                self.to = 60
            }
            self.isTimeStarted = true
        }
        .onReceive(self.time, perform: { _ in
            if self.timeDuration != 0 {
                self.timeDuration -= 1
                withAnimation(.default) {
                    self.to = CGFloat(self.timeDuration)/60
                }
            } else {
                self.timeDuration = 60
                self.to = 60
            }
        })
    }
    func formatTime() -> String {
        let minutes = Int(timeDuration) / 60 % 60
        let seconds = Int(timeDuration) % 60
        return String(format: "%02i:%02i", minutes,seconds)
    }
}

struct BlurView2: UIViewRepresentable {
    var style: UIBlurEffect.Style
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
        let view = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
        return view
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Timers are not good at keeping time. They fire when the system has resources to deal with it, so not perfectly in sync with the actual time. Your better option is to compare differences of dates. To pause or stop the timer, you just save the date at when you did it. Timers are used to regularly check something, or do something in your app. There are plenty of good tutorials that explain this for stopwatch apps.

Comment: Take a look at https://medium.com/@pwilko/how-not-to-create-stopwatch-in-swift-e0b7ff98880f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thi should be pretty simple. Keep your timer firing but return in your function if it should pause.

Add this to the start of your `.onReceive` function:

```
if isPaused{
    return
}
```

and change your `Button` to:

```
isPaused.toggle()
```